# draw polygon on map using finger

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the Google maps api V2 for android.
I am able to do the basic stuff like adding markers on click etc.

I would now like to make my app such that the user can trace the outline 
Of a polygon  using the finger and the polygon is shown on the map.

In V1 I think it would have been done using an overlay item
How do I achieve the same in V2 of the API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In V2 you can achieve this using [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#polygons) and [OnMapClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html).

Comment: I want to drag my finger on the screen to draw the polygon. Can I do this with OnMapClickListener?

Comment: @LinusLinus No. You would have to make map non-interactive by adding a view on top of fragment and working on `MotionEvents` and `Projection`.

Comment: I am unfortunately new to android programming. I understand the concepts of MotionEvents and how Projection plays a part in going from screen coordinates to actual lat-long. I am unclear on adding the View to MapFragment part. It would be a lot of help if you can show me an example. Thanks a lot.